# SalesforceCommerceCloud-service-cloud-connector(B2C) deployment issue

Tags: apex, deployment, b2b-commerce, b2c

SalesforceCommerceCloud-service-cloud-connector(B2C) deployment issue
Hello Eveyone, I am reaching out for help with SalesforceCommerceCloud-service-cloud-connector(B2C)
https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/service-cloud-connector/blob/release/docs/setupB2CCommerce.md
This unmanaged package provided by Salesforce for connecting Salesforce b2c with Sales/Service cloud.

## issue:

I am trying to Deploy the unmanaged package as per Salesforce guidelines but all the test classes mentioned in the package fails.

Unmanaged package is deployed properly in Full copy environment which is exact copy of Production

Issue is only with Production environment deployment, any pointers to resolve the issue will be helpful.

Error:

```
SCCAccountImpl_Test.testContinueWithObject -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testContinueWithObject: line 37, column 1
2.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testPatchCustProfile_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testPatchCustProfile_One: line 112, column 1
3.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testSyncAccount_Four -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testSyncAccount_Four: line 75, column 1
4.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testSyncAccount_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testSyncAccount_One: line 46, column 1
5.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testSyncAccount_Two -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testSyncAccount_Two: line 56, column 1
6.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testPatchCustProfile_Three -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testPatchCustProfile_Three: line 131, column 1
7.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testUpsertAddressBook_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testUpsertAddressBook_One: line 86, column 1
8.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testUpsertAddressBook_Three -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testUpsertAddressBook_Three: line 104, column 1
9.  SCCAccountImpl_Test.testUpsertAddressBook_Two -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
    Stack trace: Class.SCCAccountImpl_Test.testUpsertAddressBook_Two: line 95, column 1
10.  SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.testCancelledOrder_Three -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.setup: line 13, column 1
11.  SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.testCancelledOrder_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.setup: line 13, column 1
12.  SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.testCheckOrderStatus_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.setup: line 13, column 1
13.  SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.testCheckOrderStatus_Three -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.setup: line 13, column 1
14.  SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.testCheckOrderStatus_Two -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCancelledOrderCompController_Test.setup: line 13, column 1
15.  SCCCaseImpl_Test.testContinueWithObject_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCaseImpl_Test.setup: line 33, column 1
16.  SCCCaseImpl_Test.testContinueWithObject_Two -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCaseImpl_Test.setup: line 33, column 1
17.  SCCCaseImpl_Test.testSyncContactCase_One -- System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
     Stack trace: Class.SCCCaseImpl_Test.setup: line 33, column 1
```

Comment: @pakaj Mishra your repo link is broken...

Comment: Its not broken, you need to have 2 factor authentication along with a commerce cloud license to authenticate.